# Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver - Troubleshooting and Switching Graphics Drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics

I recently installed ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver on my laptop to get away from windows and their lack of security, after finishing the install everything works fine except the animations of the OS are slightly laggy.

My laptop's has [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7620G] how can I switch between open source drivers or proprietary drivers to check which ones work best?

I can't seem to find driver settings in the menu's.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in `Software & Updates` under the `Additional Drivers` tap.

[image]

Hopefully you will find the proprietary Radeon drivers there.

Comment: My software & updates app says "No additional drivers are available" and underneath that it says "No proprietary drivers are in use" does this mean I am using the open source ubuntu drivers? The reason I ask is because my graphics seem to be working now after changing the refresh rate from 60hz to 40hz.

Comment: I seem to remember AMD/ATI is supporting development of open source driver for linux instead of releasing proprietary drivers like Nvidia. So you probably using the best driver there is available for your card. If it is just he animation is slow, you can turn it off under Appearance in gnome tweaks. `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

Comment: The animations were really slow when opening the app tray until I changed 'settings > devices > screen display > refresh rate' to the lower setting which now seems to have fixed the problem I did have animations disabled with 'gnome-tweaks' until i tried changing this setting which seems to have fixed the problem, thank you for your help.